# Sharepoint 2010 : Using infopath form content type on a document set

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Here is the situation :
- Created a web-enabled form using InfoPath and published it to the Sharepoint site as a content type named PAF Cost , uploaded the model form as well in a library on the site.
- Created a document set named PAF, which containes the PAF Cost splitting content type.
- Created a library Forms in which i allowed the document set PAF content type

When I create a new document set say PAF1, i go inside it and i go to the ribbon document/new document command and i can create one new PAF Cost frame. I can edit this form through the web interface which is correct.

Now i want this form to be automatically created when i create a new document set PAF1,
To do this i specified a template for the default content type in the document set PAF settings, and i give the .XNS form file as a template. The form gets automatically created in the document set, but when i click on it it launches Infopath, and does not open as a web form. The icon as well is different from the manual y created form which open as a web form.

How can i make this automatically created form to open as a web form ?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found a way to make it work with a .xns as template. But if you specify the .xml (just creat an empty form in the library, it's an -xml with the .xns as reference) as the template within the documentset it works fine. 
(Same goes for infopath documents created from code - I hade to use the .xml as template, to have it open in thw browser by default.)